# Magenta: how to execute shell file containing HTML code? (syntax error near unexpected token 'newline')

Tags: python, shell, tensorflow, sh, magenta

I am trying to work with the open source models offered by Magenta in Python on Ubuntu, in context of automatic music generation. I've been able to make some of the models work (like the Melody RNN one), but I'm having troubles with Coconet, more specifically, with the shell files (.sh).

The instructions are to use this command:

`sh sample_bazel.sh path_to_checkpoint`

I've made sure that the file is executable (learnt that from other similar questions on here), but I still can't figure out what the goal of this script is, and how I'm supposed to run it.
It doesn't work when running it in python or in my terminal using various commands, this is the error I get:

`line 7: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`
`line 7: < !DOCTYPE html >`

So the shell file is written in HTML, is this common? How can I make this work?
I read somewhere that the '<' and '>' should be removed, but this doesn't seem right.
I checked out a lot of similar questions but couldn't fix it.

Comment: What are the content of the scripts? Most likely it's pulling down another external script from a URL which is now a 404.

Comment: not sure, I'm not very advanced in this. this is the file:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5df7fbfbfd56e8dcf1ce6be1df100cf420200309160526/16d5d4

Comment: That file is a github view of a file, not the raw file itself. If you downloaded from github yourself, you need to click the "raw" button.

Comment: wow are you serious? damn I feel dumb, let me try it

Comment: (this was the solution btw, thank you)